# Dataframe Metrics Output Formatting on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I splitted my dataframe into two, one with having null values of a specifc column and other is null free. Then I selected a couple of metrics and tried to present them in a comparable way. I have already created the output. However, i believe this code is not very attractive and I would like to know if there is an easier way to get the output I wanted. and If I can even make it two metrics per row it would be perfect.

dataframe1 (with null):

| CRIM | ZN | INDUS | CHAS | NOX | RM | AGE | DIS | RAD | TAX | PTRATIO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.02731 | 0.0 | 7.07 | 0.0 | NaN | 6.421 | 78.9 | 4.9671 | 2.0 | 242.0 | 17.8 |
| 0.08829 | 12.5 | 7.87 | 0.0 | NaN | 6.012 | 66.6 | 5.5605 | 5.0 | 311.0 | 15.2 |
| 0.22489 | 12.5 | 7.87 | 0.0 | NaN | 6.377 | 94.3 | 6.3467 | 5.0 | 311.0 | 15.2 |

dataframe1 (without null):

| CRIM | ZN | INDUS | CHAS | NOX | RM | AGE | DIS | RAD | TAX | PTRATIO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.32711 | 0.0 | 8.07 | 0.0 | 0.538 | 6.851 | 75.9 | 3.9371 | 1.0 | 242.0 | 14.2 |
| 0.21859 | 16.5 | 8.85 | 0.0 | 0.469 | 6.124 | 61.6 | 6.5601 | 3.0 | 242.0 | 11.6 |
| 0.42282 | 13.5 | 8.85 | 0.0 | 0.458 | 6.732 | 97.3 | 5.3627 | 3.0 | 311.0 | 18.1 |

```
print('min', 'Null Free', 'With Nulls', sep='\t')
for i in housing.columns:  
    if i == 'NOX':
        pass
    else:
        print(i, "{:.2f}".format(housing_nullfree.min().T.loc[i]),"{:.2f}".format(housing_nulls.min().T.loc[i]), sep="\t\t")

print()
print('Perc25', 'Null Free', 'With Nulls', sep='\t')
for i in housing.columns:  
    if i == 'NOX':
        pass
    else:
        print(i, "{:.2f}".format(np.percentile(housing_nullfree[i], 25)),"{:.2f}".format(np.percentile(housing_nulls[i], 25)), sep="\t\t")

print()
print('mean', 'Null Free', 'With Nulls', sep='\t')
for i in housing.columns:
    if i == 'NOX':
        pass
    else:
        print(i, '{:.2f}'.format(housing_nullfree.mean().T.loc[i]),'{:.2f}'.format(housing_nulls.mean().T.loc[i]), sep="\t\t")

print()
print('median', 'Null Free', 'With Nulls', sep='\t')
for i in housing.columns:
    if i == 'NOX':
        pass
    else:
        print(i, '{:.2f}'.format(np.median(housing_nullfree[i])), '{:.2f}'.format(np.median(housing_nulls[i])), sep="\t\t")
                                 
print()
print('Perc75', 'Null Free', 'With Nulls', sep='\t')
for i in housing.columns:  
    if i == 'NOX':
        pass
    else:
        print(i, "{:.2f}".format(np.percentile(housing_nullfree[i], 75)),"{:.2f}".format(np.percentile(housing_nulls[i], 75)), sep="\t\t")

print()
print('Perc90', 'Null Free', 'With Nulls', sep='\t')
for i in housing.columns:  
    if i == 'NOX':
        pass
    else:
        print(i, "{:.2f}".format(np.percentile(housing_nullfree[i], 90)),"{:.2f}".format(np.percentile(housing_nulls[i], 90)), sep="\t\t")
    
print()
print('max', 'Null Free', 'With Nulls', sep='\t')
for i in housing.columns:  
    if i == 'NOX':
        pass
    else:
        print(i, "{:.2f}".format(housing_nullfree.max().T.loc[i]),"{:.2f}".format(housing_nulls.max().T.loc[i]), sep="\t\t")
```

my output:

```
min   Null Free   With Nulls
CRIM        0.01        0.02
ZN          0.00        0.00
INDUS       0.46        1.25
CHAS        0.00        0.00
RM          3.56        4.65
AGE         2.90        6.50
DIS         1.13        1.20
RAD         1.00        1.00
TAX        188.00       187.00
PTRATIO     12.60       13.00
B           0.32        27.49
LSTAT       1.73        2.96
NOX_cat     0.00        1.00

Perc25  Null Free   With Nulls
CRIM        0.08        0.06
ZN          0.00        0.00
INDUS       5.32        4.05
CHAS        0.00        0.00
RM          5.88        6.01
AGE        45.70        42.40
DIS         2.06        2.51
RAD         4.00        4.00
TAX       281.00        276.00
PTRATIO     17.40       16.60
B          374.68       378.95
LSTAT       7.18        6.90
NOX_cat     0.00        1.00

mean    Null Free   With Nulls
CRIM        3.78        2.38
ZN         10.70        16.20
INDUS       11.42       9.09
CHAS        0.07        0.08
RM          6.27        6.36
AGE        68.96        65.77
DIS         3.70        4.49
RAD         9.59        9.28
TAX        410.89       388.90
PTRATIO     18.47       18.33
B          353.87       377.10
LSTAT       12.89       10.90
NOX_cat     0.00        1.00

median  Null Free   With Nulls
CRIM        0.29        0.15
ZN          0.00        0.00
INDUS       9.90        7.38
CHAS        0.00        0.00
RM          6.18        6.31
AGE        78.10        72.70
DIS         3.09        3.95
RAD         5.00        5.00
TAX        334.00       307.00
PTRATIO     19.10       18.60
B          391.13       392.52
LSTAT       11.66       9.45
NOX_cat     0.00        1.00

Perc75  Null Free   With Nulls
CRIM        3.69        1.61
ZN         12.50        25.00
INDUS       18.10       13.92
CHAS        0.00        0.00
RM          6.59        6.79
AGE        94.30        93.30
DIS         5.10        5.72
RAD        24.00        8.00
TAX       666.00        432.00
PTRATIO     20.20       20.20
B         396.24        395.59
LSTAT       17.12       14.10
NOX_cat     0.00        1.00

Perc90  Null Free   With Nulls
CRIM        11.00       7.99
ZN          40.00       70.00
INDUS       19.58       18.10
CHAS        0.00        0.00
RM          7.16        7.04
AGE        98.80        97.40
DIS         6.75        7.83
RAD        24.00        24.00
TAX        666.00       666.00
PTRATIO     20.90       20.20
B          396.90       396.90
LSTAT       23.28       18.80
NOX_cat     0.00        1.00

max    Null Free    With Nulls
CRIM        88.98       24.39
ZN         100.00       90.00
INDUS       27.74       18.10
CHAS        1.00        1.00
RM          8.78        8.25
AGE        100.00       100.00
DIS        10.71        12.13
RAD        24.00        24.00
TAX        711.00       666.00
PTRATIO     22.00       22.00
B          396.90       396.90
LSTAT       37.97       28.28
NOX_cat     0.00        1.00
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question by  showing a smaller dataset  (say 2 or 3 rows), then give a sample of the input sets, (with nulls & null free), then provide an example of what output you want?

Comment: @itprorh66 i put some extra information to the question. by the way, i already have an output but i wonder if i can do it in a nicer way

Comment: have you explored use of the df.describe() method?  This will characterize your dataset by column statistics to include: count, mean, std_dev, min, 25%, 50%, 75%, & max.  Using the describe result you could easily build a result frame as needed.